# About errors in state management using freezed and StateNotifier in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote the following code using freezed with the intention of managing the loading state when the sign-in button is pressed on the sign-in page.

```
//sign_in_page_state.dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart';

part 'sign_in_page_state.freezed.dart';



@freezed
abstract class SignInPageState with _$SignInPageState {
  const factory SignInPageState.noError() = _NoError;

  const factory SignInPageState.error(String errorText) = _Error;

  const factory SignInPageState.loading(String loadingText) = _Loading;
}

class SignInPageModel extends StateNotifier<SignInPageState>{
  SignInPageModel(SignInPageState state):super(state);

  void startSignIn(){
    state=SignInPageState.loading("now signing in,please wait a minute.");
  }

  void successSignIn(){
    state=SignInPageState.noError();
  }

  void errorSignIn(){
    state=SignInPageState.error("failed to sign in.");
  }
}
```

```
//signin_page.dart
class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = 'sign in';

  static Widget create(BuildContext context,){
    return StateNotifierProvider<SignInPageModel, SignInPageState>(
      create:(_)=>SignInPageModel(SignInPageState.noError(),),
      child:SignInPage(),
    );
  }
```

At this time, the following error will appear.
[image]

```
//error message
'SignInPageModel' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateNotifier<SignInPageState>' of the type parameter 'Controller'.   
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'StateNotifier<SignInPageState>'.
```

No matter how I look at it, SignInPageModel is a subclass of StateNotifier<SignInPageState>.

and I also define and use UploadMovieState in much the same way as SignInPageState, but I don't get this error at all.
so I can't figure out the cause at all.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the State of SignInPage was declared as follows, it was caused by the same name 'SignInPageState'.
I'm sorry I asked a really silly question lol

```
class SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
    //...
```